# Rails paperclip styles not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, styles, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm trying to apply styles to an image uploaded by paperclip, to save the original and a thumbnail.

```
has_attached_file :image, styles => { :thumb => "100x100", :original => "100%"},
                          :path => "images/:id/:style_:basename.:extension"
```

Is not working, it only saves the original, even I delete the `:original => "100%"` part.
And I've ImageMagick installed and the gem `rmagick`.

Comment: The "original" is automatically saved, normally you don't need the :original part anyway. And for the bug, I can't figure out why it's not working. Maybe because of the :path? Try to remove it and see if it's working.

Comment: How are you using it in your view?

Comment: Did you checked in public/system folder if thumbnail is getting saved?

Comment: I am not sure this would solve the problem, but you could try to add the option '!' to your thumb style, this will ignore aspect ratio, check this http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#noaspect
Also try to resize using ImageMagick in your terminal and see the output.

Comment: 1) If I remove the path, it saves only the original in public/system.
2) I'm not showing in a view, I send the images through an API.
3) The thumbnail is not saved in public/system.
4) I've tried using `convert` from shell, and it works.

Comment: Fixed! I was using paperclip 3.0.4 version, after install 3.4.0 version, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

:thumb => "100x100" s/b :thumb => "100x100>"

you forgot the >

see doc:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Answer (score -1):

remove this `:original => "100%"`

Comment: Please add a explanation to make this more understandable to the asker.